# Best approach for parsing html string Programatically without appending to DOM

Tags: javascript, html-parsing

I am currently building a parser and compiler to handle my own custom 2-way data bindings, everything is working fine however it involves me appending my template string via `.innerHTML` which is not very efficient.

When parsing I need to access certain DOM methods such as `.getElementsByTagName('*')` and perform other traversal tasks so I am unable to use DOC fragments and due to the string being `text/html` am unable to use [DOMParser()](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_parser.asp) which uses `text/xml`

Does anyone know of a simple solution that would let me parse my string and store elements in storage where I can then manipulate and bind events before before appending to the DOM?

Here is a stripped down version of the current html string insertion which I am trying to avoid:

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    var globalModel = function(data){
        this.templateString = data.template || '';
        this.template = data.node || document.body;
        this.initialise();
    };

    globalModel.prototype = {
        initialise: function(){
            this.template .innerHTML = this.templateString;
            this.compile();
        },
        compile: function(){
            var nodes = this.template.getElementsByTagName('*');
            //calling other methods with nodes, parsing and doing more traversal
        }
    }

    var myModule = new globalModel({
        template: '<div>Your email is {{email}} <input type="text" data-relation="email" /> {{test}} </div>'
    });

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing this:

```
var temp = document.createElement('div')
temp.innerHTML = this.templateString;
```

then you can move all the children to this.containerNode after doing the binding.

Comment: Thanks this worked, now I just need to unwrap that div from the template before render